# Jenkinsfile for different operating system like Windows and Linux

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkinsfile to create a pipeline.
If this pipeline should  be executed on different operating system like Linux and Windows, which is the best approach to manage this situation?

I mean, do I need to create two different Jenkinsfile? One for Windows and another one for Linux in order to manage the different commands/shell operating systems?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `isUnix()` function that will return `TRUE` if the node that you are running on is a Unix like OS (Unix/MacOS/Linux), or `FALSE` if it is running on Windows.  You should be able to implement a if check

```
script {
    if (isUnix()) {
       //Linux Environment
       sh ./script.sh
     }
     else {
       //Windows Environment
       bat batchfile.bat
     }
 }
```